# NullPointerException when using EntityManager

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data

I'm trying to implement a custom batch save with Spring Data, but when you use the @PersistenceContext annotation I get a NullPointerException. 
I have another repository extending my custom repository and if I understood correctly, it should let me inject the EntityManager into my impl class.

Custom repository:

```
public interface FRObjectRepositoryCustom {

    void save(List<FRObject> list);
}
```

Regular JPA repository:

```
public interface FRObjectRepository extends JpaRepository<FRObject, FRObjectKey>, FRObjectRepositoryCustom {...}
```

And my implementation class:

```
public class FRObjectRepositoryCustomImpl implements FRObjectRepositoryCustom {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

@Override
public void save(List<FRObject> list) {
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        em.persist(list.get(i));
        if (i % 50 == 0 && i > 0) {
            em.flush();
            em.clear();
        }
    }
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You have to inject EntityManager in order to initialize that. create a constructor in Impl class :

@Inject
FRObjectRepositoryCustomImpl(EntityManager em){
this.em=em;
}

Comment: @PriyaJain just a quick though the same code works for me without injecting em . is it because i am using spring boot ?

Comment: You haven't posted the code using this repo, nor the stack trace of the exception, which is a bad idea. But Spring-data-jpa expects your custom class tobe named FRObjectRepositoryImpl, not FRObjectRepositoryCustomImpl.

Comment: Post the stacktrace. I can't read minds anymore.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring-boot+JPA EntityManager inject fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30753579/spring-bootjpa-entitymanager-inject-fails)

Comment: Please post the stacktrace and your dependencies