# What is the JPQL equivalent of the PostgreSQL date_trunc('day', (entity.date AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')) function when using JPA and Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jpql

What is the JPQL/JPA/Hibernate equivalent of the database function `date_trunc('day', (entity.date AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'))` ?

I need to be rounding down to full days (and weeks, etc.) in a Spring Boot application with Hibernate running on top of a Postgresql database. This query is possible in native postgresql but I haven't figured out how to do it in Hibernate yet. The timezone (like 'UTC', 'Europe/Amsterdam') and date part (like 'day', 'year') may vary so I can't just set it to a default.

I found an ancient post at the Hibernate forums without any replies: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=990451

I also found a related StackOverflow question where the poster directly wants to select on a date as a certain timezone. It has no replies though: [HQL equivalent of Postgres' "datetime at time zone"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53103389/hql-equivalent-of-postgres-datetime-at-time-zone)

My whole query (without the where) looks like this so a different way to achieve this would be ok too.

```
"SELECT NEW " + AggregateQueryEntity.class.getName() +
                "(date_trunc('" + aggregationPeriod.toString() +
                "', a.date), a.alertConfiguration.id.id, a.alertConfiguration.name, a.alertLevel, count(*)) from Alert a" +
                whereClause.toString() +
                " GROUP BY 1, a.alertConfiguration.id.id, a.alertConfiguration.name, a.alertLevel" +    //column 1 is the truncated date
                " ORDER BY 1, alertLevel DESC"
```

> Edit: comments on answer.

Vlad's answer is great, I adapted it some more to also have the date part as a variable. Additionally I had to override the standard Hibernate behavior which generates `Date` columns as `timestamp without timezone` and explicitly make them `timestamp with timezone` by putting this on my column definition:

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE") private Date date;
```

For further reading, see https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_timestamp_.28without_time_zone.29

It's also still a good idea to use the Hibernate property `hibernate.jdbc.time_zone`, according to Vlad's other blog post https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-store-date-time-and-timestamps-in-utc-time-zone-with-jdbc-and-hibernate/ and start your JVM in UTC. I had to do this too in order to fix all my timezone issues.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As explained in the [Hibernate User Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-functions), yu can use either the `EXTRACT` function:

```
List<Integer> days = entityManager
.createQuery(
    "select extract( day from c.timestamp ) " +
    "from Call c ", Integer.class )
.getResultList();
```

or the `day` function:

```
List<Integer> days = entityManager
.createQuery(
    "select day( c.timestamp ) " +
    "from Call c ", Integer.class )
.getResultList();
```

### Registering the DATE_TRUNC function using the `MetadataBuilderContributor`

If you need to use the `AT TIMEZONE` as well, you need to register the PostgreSQL function like this:

```
public class SqlFunctionsMetadataBuilderContributor
        implements MetadataBuilderContributor {

    @Override
    public void contribute(MetadataBuilder metadataBuilder) {
        metadataBuilder.applySqlFunction(
                "date_trunc",
                new SQLFunctionTemplate(
                        StandardBasicTypes.TIMESTAMP,
                        "date_trunc('day', (?1 AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'))"
                )
        );
    }
}
```

### Configuring the `MetadataBuilderContributor` using JPA persistence.xml

Now, you need to provide the `SqlFunctionsMetadataBuilderContributor` to Hibernate via the `hibernate.metadata_builder_contributor` configuration property:

```
<property>
    name="hibernate.metadata_builder_contributor" 
    value="com.vladmihalcea.book.hpjp.hibernate.query.function.SqlFunctionsMetadataBuilderContributor"
</property>
```

### Configuring the `MetadataBuilderContributor` using Spring Boot

If you're using Spring Boot, you need to add the following configuration to the `application.properties` file:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.metadata_builder_contributor=com.vladmihalcea.book.hpjp.hibernate.query.function.SqlFunctionsMetadataBuilderContributor
```

### Testing data

Then, assuming you have the following `Post` entity in the database:

```
Post post = new Post();
post.setId(1L);
post.setTitle(
    "High-Performance Java Persistence"
);
post.setCreatedOn(
    Timestamp.valueOf(
        LocalDateTime.of(2018, 11, 23, 11, 22, 33)
    )
);

entityManager.persist(post);
```

### Using the DATE_TRUNC in JPQL

You can call the `date_trunc` function in JPQL like this:

```
Tuple tuple = entityManager
.createQuery(
    "select p.title as title, date_trunc(p.createdOn) as creation_date " +
    "from Post p " +
    "where p.id = :postId", Tuple.class)
.setParameter("postId", 1L)
.getSingleResult();

assertEquals(
    "High-Performance Java Persistence", 
    tuple.get("title")
);

assertEquals(
    Timestamp.valueOf(
        LocalDateTime.of(2018, 11, 23, 0, 0, 0)
    ), 
    tuple.get("creation_date")
);
```

### Customizing the time zone passed to DATE_TRUNC

If you want to customize the time zone, just pass the time zone as a parameter like this:

```
public static class SqlFunctionsMetadataBuilderContributor
        implements MetadataBuilderContributor {

    @Override
    public void contribute(MetadataBuilder metadataBuilder) {
        metadataBuilder.applySqlFunction(
                "date_trunc",
                new SQLFunctionTemplate(
                        StandardBasicTypes.TIMESTAMP,
                        "date_trunc('day', (?1 AT TIME ZONE ?2))"
                )
        );
    }
}
```

Now, you can call the `date_trunc` function as follows:

```
Tuple tuple = entityManager
.createQuery(
    "select p.title as title, date_trunc(p.createdOn, :timezone) as creation_date " +
    "from Post p " +
    "where p.id = :postId", Tuple.class)
.setParameter("postId", 1L)
.setParameter("timezone", "UTC")
.getSingleResult();
```

### Test cases

I created the following test cases in my high-performance-java-persistence GitHub repository, and they run just fine:

- [`DateTruncUtcFunctionTest`](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/high-performance-java-persistence/blob/56b27995bc4b5b6ee6913fa1f0f584d8db97bace/core/src/test/java/com/vladmihalcea/book/hpjp/hibernate/query/function/DateTruncUtcFunctionTest.java)
- [`DateTruncTimeZoneFunctionTest`](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/high-performance-java-persistence/blob/07c86357e9dfc9e4029c06e70e1a62a52481f157/core/src/test/java/com/vladmihalcea/book/hpjp/hibernate/query/function/DateTruncTimeZoneFunctionTest.java)

Comment: Extract isn't quite the same as date_trunc though. date_trunc still gives me the whole date. I use this in a group by query to get a count for a certain amount of dates. The time zone is variable. I edited my full query into my post now. Looks like I could go your way or just go full native query instead.

Comment: Check out my updated answer. It even contains a link to a test case which works like a charm.

Comment: Sounds good, although I do need to pass the time zone id string and the truncation period (hour, minute) as well, they're variable.

Comment: You can do that as well. Just pass a new argument.

Comment: Right, I could just do `StandardBasicTypes.TIMESTAMP,"date_trunc('?1', (?2 AT TIME ZONE '?3'))"` and call it with `date_trunc(aggregationPeriod, p.createdOn, timezoneId)` I guess?

Comment: Check out my updated answer, and the associated test cases.

Comment: Alright thanks, I hope I can replace the period value with a parameter as well without any complaints from the database. Will proceed with this tomorrow and accept the answer. I'll move this discussion to chat in a bit.

Comment: As a last thing, this <property>
    name="hibernate.metadata_builder_contributor" goes into the pom or is that something hibernate-specific?

Comment: Nope. It goes in the persistence.xml file

Comment: I've updated the function and theoretically it should work, however I haven't been able to register the function yet. Spring Boot doesn't use persistence.xml by default and looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30753579/spring-bootjpa-entitymanager-inject-fails/35672704#35672704 it isn't trivial to do so without overriding all automatic Hibernate configuration by Spring Boot. I also tried adding the properties to application.properties but they don't seem to get picked up. Any ideas?

Comment: If you add the `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.metadata_builder_contributor` configuration property in the `application.properties` file of Spring Boot, it should work just fine.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! Perhaps you could edit that in your post for future Spring Boot/Hibernate newbies, so I can move this entire conversation to chat.

Comment: That's a good idea. I updated the answer to include that as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184389/discussion-between-sebastiaan-van-den-broek-and-vlad-mihalcea).

Answer (score 6):

You can simply call a postgres function using the following syntax -

```
function('date_trunc', 'month', date)
```

As an example -

```
select distinct w from YourModel w where studentId=:studentId and function('date_trunc', 'month', date) = :month
```

Answer (score 1):

In additions to @karthiks3000 answer, if you use Hibernate’s PostgreSQL dialect, you can simply call its functions in a JPQL query:

```
date_trunc('month', date)
```

Source: [How do you call a PostgreSQL function with Hibernate?](https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tips-call-postgresql-function/)